# Do I have a virus? What is this green icon?

Tags: windows-7, virus

Just got a new computer at work and was just starting to install all of my required software on it.

I downloaded something and may have installed it by mistake (it could have been TortoiseSVN).

Immediately after starting and logging in:

Task Switcher:
[image]

Desktop after switching to window with green icon:
[image]

Do I have a virus?  I installed AVG but it did not find any viruses. What steps should I take?

Comment: I don't see what you are talking about.

Comment: @Ramhound You don't see the rectangle in the uppoer left corner of the screen, and the left icon in the task switcher?

Comment: The green icon looks like some sort of installer. What's probably happening is that you installed a piece of old software that uses an old installer that isn't quite compatible with Windows 7 (or 64-bit if your system is that). So, the installation did not and cannot complete and just hangs there. You will want to disable and remove it with something like Autoruns because you won't be able to use the normal Uninstall function in *Add/Remove Programs* since the installer does not function correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance I'd say no, looks more like a glitchy program, perhaps some kind of download manager judging from the icon? but I'd pull open task manager and see.

Press Ctrl+Shift+Esc
Click on the Processes Tab
Under View select select columns
Check Image Path Name

Try to find what you think that process is. You may be able to see it on the applications tab and see what process it is by right clicking and clicking on Go to Process. If the Image Path Name shows it running from either C:\Users... or C:\Program Data... for anything under the processes tab there is a good chance it is malware, otherwise it may be just something you accidentally installed.

You may want to scan with [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) to be safe but you'll probably be able to disable it from Programs and Features or [msconfig.exe](http://netsquirrel.com/msconfig/msconfig_win7.html).

Comment: Installed in C:\dell\DBRM\Reminder\DbrmTrayicon.exe so looks like it is broken dell crapware.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem glad you figured it out :)

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude, just because it is in that path does not guarantee it is safe. Malware frequently masquerades as legitimate software. Use something like Autoruns to disable it, and MalwareBytes/SuperAntiSpyware to scan it.

Comment: @Synetch True. this is no guarantee, but with today's malware it is less frequent to hide in that way; Most modern malware either is kept in the user space(C:\Users, C:\ProgramData) or it is root kitted into hiding. It is harder for Malware to get into Program Files on Windows 7 unless the user made a complete blunder(which it could have happened here). I'd say it is unlikely to be malware,though. However, there is no reason to not be cautious.

Answer (score 4):

That is for Dell Backup and Recovery software. We have the same problem at work on our new PC's. It loads, but then displays the gray box up in the corner like you showed. Only way to get rid of it completely is to uninstall it from the computer. It comes standard shipped from Dell installed on there.