# I can't remove a tiny window

Tags: windows, task-manager

There is a tiny window that I am unable to identify or close. It is big enough for me to move but I can't seem to stretch it to make it bigger, I can't close it. It does not appear to be any of the items listed as Applications in the Task Manager.

Is there any sort of program that allows me to identify a process by clicking on the window of the application?

I really want to know what this is. If I log out it goes away but something I am doing is causing it to re-appear.

Any ideas how best to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)'s "Find Window's Process" feature (the crosshairs on the toolbar of the Process Explorer window). Click and drag it over the window you want to identify, and Process Explorer will highlight the process it belongs to.

Comment: In addition it might be possible to resize the window. Right click on its title bar (or taskbar button), and click on "Size". Press the arrow key corresponding to the side you want to resize, and move your mouse perpendicular to that side to resize it.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bugged program. To identify it [follow my instructions for a similar post](https://superuser.com/questions/440309/do-i-have-a-virus-what-is-this-green-icon/440313#440313).

If you are still unable to identify it, you may want to use a program called [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to remove.