# Program is still loading at startup even after uninstalling

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

Dell installs a program on the machines I purchased from them called *Dell Backup and Recovery Manager*. I immediately uninstall this program from my new machines as I use a different method for my backup/recovery process.

The problem that I'm running into is that, even after uninstalling this program, it still seems to load on startup. As seen on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/440309/do-i-have-a-virus-what-is-this-green-icon/440327#440327), which I had answered previously, the program has a problem to where it only displays a portion of the program in the corner of the screen which is very annoying. The only way to get rid of the box is by closing out of the program.

The program is not showing up in the programs list when looking in the control panel, and it is not showing up in the startup folder either. So the questions would be - *How in the world is the program still loading even though it has been removed from the computer?* And *How can I prevent this program from loading in the future?*

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>**Program list**  (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Find the registry key for the .exe file that is being ran.  Sounds like the uninstaller is broken if it does not remove all the installed files.  You can also just delete the files in the installation directory.

Answer (score 2):

Just because a program is no longer listed in Add/Remove programs does not mean that the program is off of the system. The first thing I would do is make sure the program isn't in the Startup tab of msconfig:

1. Start -> Run -> type "msconfig" and hit enter
2. Switch to the "Startup" tab
3. Find the program and remove the check-mark on the left hand side of the item

This will prevent the program from launching at start, but will not remove the program from your computer. You can easily get the path for this startup item while in msconfig, but check to make sure it's not loading a secondary application after booting. When you notice the program is running, do the following:

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+Esc to load the task manager
2. Look for the program in the Applications tab
3. Right click on the program and click "Go to process"
4. Note the name of the process that's running and search your machine for the literal name (that is, including the file extension)

The methods listed here of terminating/removing the program don't require any extra software, although there are freeware packages that can help you more quickly/simply identify where a program is running from.

Answer (score 1):

Download *Autoruns* from  [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) .  This will give you all the applications that are started at bootup - including all those that aren't shown by Control Panel or msconfig.

Search for the task you wish to kill and untick the box.

It will also give you the path to the executable that is being run at bootup.

Answer (score 0):

just disable it and if you want to never see it again, you will need to go into the regedit command by typing regedit.  Find the strings that pertain to the program you want to exterminate and delete them.  If some of the registry items you find will not let you delete them, you will have to click on the left hand side folder that the item is in and right click to go to properties. From there you will change the permissions to add you, what ever your user name is, enabling you to act as an admistrator, to have the permissions needed to delete the such file/s you wanted to, but you did not have permission to do so. Chances are you will not have to add your user name to the permissions list, so dont worry, just find the strings in the registry you want to get rid of.